# Laravel embed image in email

Tags: laravel, email

I am trying to  embed image in email.

```
<img  src="embed({{URL::asset('storage/thumbs_250/'.$user_inf->card)}})" >
```

But nothing shows. What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this way:

```
<img src="<?php echo $message->embed($pathToImage); ?>" style="max-width: 80%;padding-top: 20px;">
```